# Cytoscape.js: calculate graph dimensions at current zoom level?

Tags: javascript, resize, cytoscape.js

I would like to resize both a) the container DOM element and b) the zoom level based on the height of my graph.

Suppose I add nodes and edges dynamically to the graph. Given a maximum zoom level (`zMax`) and a maximum container height (`cMax`), I'd like to fit according to the following rules:

- if, at the current zoom level, `z == zMax && graphHeight < cMax`, then keep the zoom level constant and resize the container to fit the graph.
- if, at the current zoom level, `graphHeight == cMax`, then reduce `z` if possible.

The problem is, I am not sure of any built-in functionality for calculating the height of the graph in pixels at the current zoom level. I suppose I could iterate over the nodes and find the lowest and highest y-values, but I am hoping there is a more efficient option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use functions that return values in rendered (on-screen) co-ordinates.

See http://js.cytoscape.org/#notation/position

See also http://js.cytoscape.org/#eles.renderedBoundingBox

E.g. `cy.elements().renderedBoundingBox().h` is the rendered height of the entire graph.